# Predicting future values using Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression

I'm using a panel dataset with a yearly range from 2014 to 2021 and I'm trying to predict future values of the `Internet Penetration Rate %` based on `GDP Per Capita` and `GDP Growth %` using Multiple Linear Regression in Python.

```
Year    Int Pen Rate %  GDP Per Capita  GDP Growth %
            
2018     70.681278       22928.33973    6.029019    
2019     73.65747575     23937.58136    3.853163833
2020     78.45526895     23184.61479   -3.677510791
2021     83.5904265      24714.24507    5.793254517
```

```
X_train = data.loc[data.index <= 2021, ['GDP Per Capita', 'GDP Growth %']]
X_test = data.loc[data.index >= 2022, ['GDP Per Capita', 'GDP Growth %']]
y_train = data.loc[data.index <= 2021, 'Int Pen Rate %']
y_test = data.loc[data.index.isin([2022, 2023, 2024]), 'Int Pen Rate %']
y_pred = regressor2.predict(X_test)
```

I created 3 new observations for years 2022-2024 and I filled them with the median value and when I predict the values I get this result that is almost the same as the median value: `[67.43485477 67.43485278 67.43485278]`.

How can I make a more accurate prediction?

Comment: What happens if you predict with linear regression for the years where you actually have data? Aren't also the predictions very close to the median? If data isn't too asymmetric, you would expect that.

Comment: The predicted values don't follow a linear growth  in the continuation of 2021...

Comment: What do you mean by _I filled them with the median value_? IIUC you created the data for 2022-2024 with feature values that are the median of those features in previous years. Linear regression doesn't understand about _time_: whether some features correspond to 2023 or 1876 is exactly the same. As suggested in one answer, you may have to use another model to predict the values for the features in 2022-2024.

Comment: So what ARIMA does. However I came across another question here that basically asked the same thing. He used time as a linear variable among others and performed a Multiple Regression to predict future values. You split the data into test and train set, then for X_train you filter the observations from 2014 to 2021 and for X_test you filter for 2022-2024 and do the same for y. Finally, you make the predictions using the linear regressor that you used to fit X_train and y_train on X_test. According to the answer below the inaccuracy of the prediction was due to the incompleteness of the model.

Comment: Yes, but then you are using real data from 2022-2024 for X_test, that is not like the one in X_train. You said that you generated the data for X_test with medians (from 2014 to 2021 data?). So, your X_test looks more like an stereotype of the 2014-2021 period.

Answer (score 0):

If the model is too simple, it might not capture the underlying trends and patterns of the data well. In your case, you have a simple linear regression model with two features. This might not be complex enough to capture the underlying trends and patterns of your data. With this amount of data, the training data is also too little - unless you're getting more data somewhere else (not shown in the example).

The features you've included might not be sufficient or strong predictors of internet penetration rate. You may want to include more features such as education level, infrastructure development, government policies etc.

Filling in future GDP data with the median is not necessarily a good strategy. Future GDP is likely to follow some trend, rather than staying constant. You might want to use some time-series forecasting method to predict future GDP per capita and GDP growth % first, then use those predicted values as inputs to your current model.

You are treating this as a simple regression problem, but your data actually has a time component. There are other models employing Neural Networks which can handle such data more appropriately as they can capture temporal dynamics which a linear regression model can't.

In conclusion, I think you need more data.
"The more data, the better". If you only have a few years of data, it might be hard to capture the underlying trend. Getting more data can help the model understand the data better and hence make better predictions.

Comment: Actually, the time series starts from 2014. I didnt show the entire dataset because it occupies a lot of space and goes beyond my point of inquiry. I will add the year range in the edit, though. Also I used ARIMA for forecasting and I was able to get pretty accurate predictions of the Internet Pen Rate, but I wanted to include in my project the Linear Regression in order to capture the impact of the other variables and to observe the difference in predictions. I was thinking of adding new variables, but I wanted to do the bulk work with the simplest model and later on adopt new predictors.